# How to implement floating Snackbar animation in flutter?

Tags: android, flutter, animation, snackbar

I'm trying to implement animation in floating Snackbar in which it emerges from the bottom of the screen and moves up, just like the one in Gmail app which emerges on sliding a mail for achive. Could someone please post an example?

```
ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar(SnackBar(
                          content: Text(
                            'Product removed from cart',
                          ),
                          action: SnackBarAction(
                              label: 'Undo',
                              onPressed: () {
                               //
                              }),
                          duration: Duration(seconds: 3),
                          behavior: SnackBarBehavior.floating,
                          margin: EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 30,left: 10,right: 10),
                          animation: // **Answer Please**
                      }
```

Answer (score -2):

Import "**`fluttertoast`**" package and use like this...

```
Fluttertoast.showToast(
        msg:"Toast Message",
        toastLength: Toast.LENGTH_SHORT,
        gravity: ToastGravity.BOTTOM,
        timeInSecForIosWeb: 1,
        textColor: Colors.white,
        backgroundColor: Colors.black54,
        fontSize: 16.0)
```

Answer (score -2):

I have been trying this for days and months now, hard luck official docs doesn't give us the example of using the `animation` prop.

But I have good news, I found a workaround by using the package named [another_flushbar](https://pub.dev/packages/another_flushbar)

[image]

---

### Types

##### 1. Default SnackBar

```
          Flushbar(
            duration: const Duration(milliseconds: 3000),
            message: "Default Snackbar",
            margin: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 20),
          ).show(context);
```

##### 2. Bottom SnackBar with `easeIn` and `easeOut`

```
            Flushbar(
              animationDuration: const Duration(seconds: 2),
              forwardAnimationCurve: Curves.easeIn,
              reverseAnimationCurve: Curves.easeOut,
              duration: const Duration(milliseconds: 3000),
              flushbarPosition: FlushbarPosition.BOTTOM,
              flushbarStyle: FlushbarStyle.FLOATING,
              message: "I am Bottom Snackbar",
              margin: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 20),
            ).show(context);
```

##### 3. Top SnackBar with `easeIn` and `easeOut`

```
            Flushbar(
              animationDuration: const Duration(seconds: 2),
              forwardAnimationCurve: Curves.easeIn,
              reverseAnimationCurve: Curves.easeOut,
              duration: const Duration(milliseconds: 3000),
              flushbarPosition: FlushbarPosition.TOP,
              flushbarStyle: FlushbarStyle.FLOATING,
              message: "I am Top Snackbar",
              margin: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 20),
            ).show(context);
```

##### 4. Snackbar with `bounceInOut`

```
             Flushbar(
              animationDuration: const Duration(seconds: 2),
              forwardAnimationCurve: Curves.bounceInOut,
              reverseAnimationCurve: Curves.bounceInOut,
              duration: const Duration(milliseconds: 3000),
              flushbarPosition: FlushbarPosition.BOTTOM,
              flushbarStyle: FlushbarStyle.FLOATING,
              message: "Snackbar can bounce ",
              margin: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 20),
            ).show(context);
```

---

##### Extra:

There is an issue in [github](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/119160) related to the same problem.